# Text Highlighter directive don't work on button click from outside the directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, rangy

I have implemented a highlighter directive with assistance of rangy library.

Please have a look at current implementation of highlighter directive: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mYrEfehaTIbzvS0hePq2?p=preview `plunker`.

Here , I have button within the template which onclick toggles the selection.

Now, I want the same behaviour but this time, button needs to be outside directive template.

Can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding $watch to look out for  , I am able to handle the issue.

`scope.$watch(function(){return scope.highlight;}, function(value) {
                 cssApplier.toggleSelection();
       });`

Running code is at : http://plnkr.co/edit/mYrEfehaTIbzvS0hePq2?p=preview

Hope it helps someone.